# How to combine two values into a single key for a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I have a dictionary in the following format. The key is a concatenated string and the value is a list of tuples.

```
dictionary = {'ABC|1':[(1,10),(5,16),(15,30)],
              'ABC|2':[(9,18),(78,10),(5,10)],
              'XYZ|1':[(45,56),(72,79),(81,98),(100,120)],
              'XYZ|2':[(11,26),(78,99),(105,119),(150,178)],..........}
```

Now, I want to change the key from 'ABC|1' to 'ABC' and combining the two values of 'ABC|1' and 'ABC|2' into a single value for the key 'ABC'. Thus, the final_dict should look like this:

```
final_dict = {'ABC':[(1,10),(5,16),(15,30),(9,18),(78,10),(5,10)],
              'XYZ':[(45,56),(72,79),(81,98),(100,120),(11,26),(78,99),(105,119),(150,178)],....}
```

The approach I am trying is as follows:

```
final_dict = dict()
for key in dictionary.keys():
  new_key = key.split('|')[0]
  if new_key not in final_dict:
    value = list()
  if new_key in key:
    value.append(dictionary[key])
```

However, this is not working. Can anybody provide me a suggestion to do this? Without using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a variant:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    new_key = key.split('|')[0]
    dct[new_key].extend(value)
```

where i  use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

your solution is close but judging from your desired output you want `list.extend` and not `list.append`.

Answer (score 1):

Just some variation in your code:

```
dictionary = {'ABC|1':[(1,10),(5,16),(15,30)],
              'ABC|2':[(9,18),(78,10),(5,10)],
              'XYZ|1':[(45,56),(72,79),(81,98),(100,120)],
              'XYZ|2':[(11,26),(78,99),(105,119),(150,178)]}

final_dict = {}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    new_key = key.split('|')[0]
    if new_key not in final_dict:
        final_dict[new_key] = dictionary[key]
    else:
        final_dict[new_key].extend(dictionary[key])
```

I tried the above code and gives this output:

```
{'XYZ': [(45, 56), (72, 79), (81, 98), (100, 120), (11, 26), (78, 99), (105, 119), (150, 178)], 'ABC': [(1, 10), (5, 16), (15,
 30), (9, 18), (78, 10), (5, 10)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to build your `final_dict` by assigning to you desired key the proper value, because your initial dict has aleadry lists as value you have to extend with them the `final_dict` values:

```
final_dict = dict()
for key in dictionary.keys():
    new_key = key.split('|')[0]
    if new_key not in final_dict:
        final_dict[new_key]= dictionary[key]
    else:
        final_dict[new_key].extend(dictionary[key])
```